# System.QueryException: unexpected token: = Error is in expression '{!dosearch}' in component

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

```
public class search {
public search(){
soql = '';
service = new list<Service__c>();
}
public string soql;
public string city{get;set;}
public list<Service__c> service{get;set;}
public void dosearch(){
 soql = '';
 soql = soql + 'select id,name,Bus_Type__c,From__c from Service__c';
 soql = soql + 'Where From__c = ' + '\''+city+'\'';
 system.debug('choos=================>' +soql);
 service = new list<Service__c>();
 service = database.query(soql);// Error hear
}
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:inputText value="{!city}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!dosearch}"/> //Error
<apex:pageBlock title="Display Value">
<apex:pageblockTable Value="{!service}" var="v">
<apex:column value="{!v.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!v.Bus_Type__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have problem with string query.
Do not use string for SOQL query, until you have to do it, because dynamic SOQL is vulnerable to [SOQL Injections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm). There are two ways to prevent possible SOQL Injections for dynamic queries:

1. Use `String.escapeSingleQuotes(String)` method for your `city` parameter

`public void dosearch(){
        soql = 'select id, name, Bus_Type__c,From__c '
              +'from Service__c '
              +'where From__c = \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(city)+'\'';
        service = Database.query(soql);
}`

1. Use simple bind variables `:city`

`public void dosearch(){
     service = [
         select id, name, Bus_Type__c,From__c
         from Service__c
         where From__c = :city
     ];
}`

Comment: i need only dynamic i have requirement do another scenario

Comment: @bingi I've updated my post above with dynamic query

Comment: accept it if it helps you, so other users with same problem would have an answer

Comment: +1 from me. Can you add a point to your answer about how it also avoids the [SOQL injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) risk?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Sorry I wasn't clear: using either `:city` or `String.escapeSingleQuotes(city)` avoids the injection problem, with the former (that you had used) being cleaner. Was just asking for a mention of the risk as it is important to keep in mind with dynamic SOQL.

Comment: @KeithC Didn't understand you properly.  I've updated my answer one more time

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Your original answer (using the bind variable) was perfect because that avoids the SOQL injection risk. I was originally just asking you to point that out in your answer i.e. you answer fixed the immediate problem and also avoided the injection problem.